# View calculated fields in Project 2010

Tags: tfs, project-management, scrum, ms-project

Using Team Foundation Server 2010 with the Scrum for Team System v3 template, I'm not able to view calculated fields (specifically the Work Remaining field) in Project 2010.  If I export my Project Backlog Items into Project, the "Remaining Work" value shows up for each Sprint Backlog Task (since it's not a calculated field), but doesn't roll-up for the PBI.  Does anyone know how to make this work?  Is there a field mapping I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, turns out there was a field mapping I was missing.  I mapped the Scrum.v3.WorkRemaining field to a custom Number field in Project, and I was then able to add that column to my Project plan!